# Accessing IBus and IConfiguration in CustomErrorHandler

Tags: c#, rebus

I have created a Custom Error Handler in rebus inheriting IErrorHandler as

```
 public class CustomErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{

    IBus bus;
    IConfiguration configuration;

    public CustomErrorHandler(IBus bus,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public async Task HandlePoisonMessage(TransportMessage 
      transportMessage, ITransactionContext transactionContext, Exception 
      exception)
    {---

This is to enable me access bus and configuration instance in my error handler.
```

However when I try to register handler

```
  services.AddRebus(configure => configure
  .Options(o =>
                {
                    o.Register<IErrorHandler>(c => new 
                    CustomErrorHandler(c.Get<IBus>(), 
                    c.Get<IConfiguration>()));


                 })...
```

I get a stack overflow exception.

However if I create an Error Handler that has no parameters than it is fine.

Kindly help on how to get an instance of IBus and IConfiguration in the created CustomErrorHandler.

I want to use it like the following:

```
   public async Task HandlePoisonMessage(TransportMessage 
   transportMessage, ITransactionContext transactionContext, Exception 
     exception)
    {
        int MaxDeferCount = this.configuration.GetValue<int> 
         ("Settings:MaxDeferCount");
        int deferCount = 1;
        if (transportMessage.Headers.ContainsKey("rbs2-defer-count"))
        {
            deferCount = int.Parse(transportMessage.Headers["rbs2-defer- 
             count"]);
        }
        if (deferCount <= MaxDeferCount)
        {
            deferCount++;
            var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 * deferCount);
            var additionalHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "rbs2-defer-count", deferCount.ToString()}
            };

            await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Defer(delay, 
             additionalHeaders);
        }
        else
        {
            var details = exception.Message;

            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {Headers.SourceQueue, 
                             transportMessage.Headers["rbs2-sender- 
                              address"]},
                            {Headers.ErrorDetails, details}
                        };
            await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.
            Forward("rebus_claims_processing_errors", headers);

        }
```

What is the proper way to do that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you able to get a stack trace?

Comment: Also explicitly inject the settings value, no need to inject `IConfiguration`.

Comment: The stack overflow is most likely from a circular reference related to `IBus`

Comment: Since you're dealing with the raw `TransportMessage` in your error handler, it would probably be sufficient and much better to get the `ITransport` injected

Comment: Also it's true what @Nkosi said about the circular reference

Comment: I have been able to Inject the ITransport as suggested. With it I can do some tasks related to transport. But I see IErrorHandler as a very important piece of logic that can perform the task of deferring messages and any extra task centrally. I still however cannot figure out how can I defer a message for a specified time in an IErrorHandler given the injected ITransport instance. This would accomplish my goal.

Comment: you can delay the processing of a message by attaching a `rbs2-deferred-until`-header (look [here](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Headers.cs#L80-L83)), setting the value to the ISO8601-encoded time of the earliest point in time when the message can be consumed. You can basically send the message to any Rebus queue, as long as that queue has a timeout manager configured.